# How to send multiple value and file correspond to each other

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I have multiple textbox and file which is correspond to each other:
     [view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7ILi.png)

```
  @ViewChildren('images') images;

 let fi=this.images['_results'];
 let formData= new FormData(); 
 formData.append('car', JSON.stringify(data)); //values of textbox (array)
 for (let index = 0; index < fi.length; index++) {
 formData.append('car_image', fi[index].nativeElement.files[0]); //files
 }
```

Note:file is not required so the index of both arrays will have a mismatch in backend,so how to sent this data through ajax or how can i handle this in the backend(node.js)

Comment: What is the type of fi and  formData here ?

Comment: updated my question

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the data for textbox and files into one object. Something like this:

`formdata.append('car', JSON.stringify({text:data, image: fi[index].nativeElement.files[0]) })`

Comment: You will need to modify the server side code accordingly

Comment: ok but can a file be converted to json,i am getting image as {} while sending.